# Android Programming: Can a particular date be converted as button?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a small app, where the goal is to upload an image, when a date is clicked. The image files are stored in `mm-dd-yyyy` format. Suppose, I click 01-MAY-2018, that corresponding image must get uploaded.

I tried to launch a new activity by calling `Intent in from the calendar class`, but the activity is not getting launched.

This is my calendar class code. How can I set a particular date as button? I tried looking at other examples, but did not find much help.

```
Calendar Class

public class CalendarApp extends AppCompatActivity {

CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_app);
    initializeCalendar();
}

public void initializeCalendar(){

    calendar=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    // sets whether to show the week number.
    calendar.setShowWeekNumber(false);

    //Set first day of Week as Monday

    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);

    //Set Background color for the Selected Week

    calendar.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    //Set colors for the date of unfocussed month

    calendar.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    //Set colors for separators line between weeks

    calendar.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    //Set colors for the vertical bars between the selected start date and the selected end date

    calendar.setSelectedDateVerticalBar(R.color.darkgreen);

    //Set the listener to be notified upon selected date change

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
         public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(CalendarApp.this, Image_View.class));
            }

        }
    );

}
```

}

```
Image_View.java

public class Image_View extends Activity {

Button button;
ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Click);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.may_1st_2018);
        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: When you clicked on a Date, does your `Toast message` being shown? Can you show your `Image_View ` class code? I suppose your `Image_View` is a class that entends `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Yes, the ToastMessage shows, and the date gets displayed

Comment: Pass the date using a Bundle in the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this :

```
calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
         public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(day==30 && month==4 && year==2018)
                 {
                  startActivity(new Intent(CalendarApp.this, Image_View.class).putExtra("date",day+"_"+month+"_"+year));
                 }

            }

        }
    );
```

Also don't forget to add the Image_View activity in manifest.

Comment: Thanks, how can I pass dynamic date?

Comment: In this callback you will get date based on your date selection in date picker. Hence it is eventually dynamic

Comment: pass the date using extra in the intent. See my edited code